# Mismatch Error where there shouldn't be

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro, but it's currently returning "mismatch error".

When I take out the "ListSheets = SheetName" part, it works fine, but of course doesn't output what I am looking for.

I don't understand the error, because both sides of the problem line of code should both be strings.

```
Function ListSheets() As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim sRow As Integer
Dim mNum As Integer
Dim sName() As String
Dim SheetName() As String
Dim Width As Integer
Width = 8


'initialize sheet name list
sRow = LastRow("Category List", 1)
mNum = Cells(sRow, 1)

ReDim sName(1, sRow)
ReDim SheetName(mNum)

'copy sheet list
For i = 2 To sRow
    sName(0, i) = Cells(i, 1)
    sName(1, i) = Cells(i, 1) & " - " & Cells(i, 2)
Next i

'transform list to good list
k = 2
For i = 1 To mNum
    If IsNumeric(sName(0, k)) Then
        If i = sName(0, k) Then
            SheetName(i) = sName(1, k)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    End If

    If i = 100 Then
        k = k + 2
    ElseIf i = 200 Then
        k = k + 2
    ElseIf i = 500 Then
        k = k + 2
    End If

Next i

ListSheets = SheetName

End Function
```

Comment: `SheetName` is a `String()` (an array).  `ListSheets` is a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your return type to String() instead of String.

Comment: Won't work (AFAIK).   Sorry, yes it will work.  But you have to be careful to  dimension the string array it is being returned to as simply `Dim x() As String: x = ListSheets()`

Comment: Explain why you think that. It seems that the intention was to return an array.

Comment: What I worked out is that it won't work if you tried to return it to a explicitly dimensioned array, you have to return it to an undimensioned array.  I.e. if you knew it was going to return an array with 5 elements, you can't do `Dim x(1 To 5) As String: x = ListSheets()`, you have to return it to an array declared simply as `Dim x() As String`.  (Or I guess you can access specific elements as, for instance, `MsgBox ListSheets()(4)`.)

Comment: Sorry, (I think) I just worked out why you were confused by my comment - I was referring to how it gets used by the **calling** program, not about any change to the `ListSheets` function - your fix is all that is required to get `ListSheets` to work.